# Pageless scroll loads the page 2 contents of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am using pageless plugin (https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless) for pagination. I have two tabs which have the same div id. So when I click on the first tab and immediately click on the second tab, the contents from page 2(of first tab) are appended in the results of the second tab. This is happening because the pagination request is sent after some delay. Is there way to fix this without changing the div id for both the tabs?

EDIT:

What I understand from comments is: OP has a div that has pageless contents in a tabbed view. When the first tab loads and he scrolls a bit and clicks on next tab whilst the 2nd page of first tab is still being processed, by then the tab 2 contents are loaded and then comes page 2 of first tab.

Comment: An id should always be unique, that is kind of the definition...

Comment: no two div's should have the same id in the first place

Comment: @Alfie  Am not using two different divs with the same id..The entire div is being replaced in the second tab. While that happens, the entire content of the current page is removed. But this is creating a problem when the pagination request from the first tab is being delayed(so the content  shows up in the second tab)..

Comment: You may try `jQuery.pagelessReset();` onclick of 2nd tab